# How to exchange space with two characters?

Tags: linux, filter, terminal, cut, tr

I guess that topic explains a lot in this subject. I have to exchange all horizontal spaces with "??" in given file. Of course, everything is about LINUX terminal.

Here are available filters (I can use only these!):

- cat
- cut
- tr
- head
- tail
- sort
- uniq
- wc
- tee

No Bash scripts, only these.

Comment: Linux terminal is a serial interface. It can only show what a process prints, and send what you type to that process. In order to program, you need a programming language. A terminal is not a language. Nothing from your list is. Bash is a language. If do not intend to program, you are at a wrong site.

Comment: That wasn't helpful, Sir. I'm looking for help with a task somehow connected with programming and I've seen questions like mine on stackoverflow. Pretty similar, but not helpful at all. 

I am not Linux specialist. I'm just looking for a help with given task.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cut`:

```
$ cat file
foo bar baz
$ cut --output-delimiter='??' -d ' ' -f 1- file
foo??bar??baz
```

Comment: Very nice +1! This does require GNU cut however which hopefully satisfies the OP lecturers requirements.